# user's account backup and restore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backup, restore

I am currently working on a project and i would like my users to be able to backup/restore theirs accounts.

I am looking for a rails plugin/gem that would easily do that, ie :

> current_user.backup()
>
> => backup_file
>
> current_user.restore(backup_file)
>
> => database import/replace

I don't know if my question is very clear, but i would like to backup every user's related object (posts, comments, etc) and to be able to restore them from a backup file.

Thanks per advance,

Cédric.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such gem b/c user data is very specific to each project.

You will have to write it yourself.